# Launching Spyder from portable installation of Anaconda

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder

Python beginner here.

On my machine I have a portable installation of Anaconda in C:\Python\2020_11.

My goal would be to use the Spyder which is included in my installation as an IDE but I seem not to be able even to run it.

I am in an organization where I have no access to the internet.

Below I took three snips of folders and their structure that should be relevant.
I can of course provide you with more details if needed.

[image: Main folder]
[image: Scripts]
[image: Lib/site-packages]

So I would like to know how I launch Spyder (simply running Scripts/spyder.exe seems to do nothing), possibly in a very easy way, i.e. without having to open a terminal and type a lot of commands (ideally I would like to have an icon on the desktop and to just be able to double click on it).